# How can I copy 10GB files onto a 64GB USB drive?

Tags: backup, usb

I have Virtual machine images

[image]

that I wanted to back up on a USB Drive so I bought a PNY64GB Drive

[image]

which was big enough for the IE8 3.36GB pvm file as seen in details

[image]

However when I try to add any of the othe other .pvm files which are 12, 11 and 14 GBs, I get

[image]

How can I fit the other .pmv's on the drive which should be big enough.

Comment: You'll need to use Disk Utility and format it as HFS+. FAT doesn't support files larger that 4GB (I think)

Comment: Yes i reformatted as one of the OSX options as I only need it on macs and that worked. You can post that as an answer.  Please include a screenshot of the format options.  I can't do that right now while the copies are stil running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Disk Utility and format it as HFS+. FAT doesn't support files larger that 4GB (I think).
Go to Disk Utility and select the drive. Then erase it and select the format as `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`. You can name it whatever you'd like.